# Pascal VOC Class Segmentation: Ground-truth pixel labeling for training

Tags: python, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network, labeling, semantic-segmentation

I just started to work on the Pascal VOC segmentation dataset. But I have trouble understanding the colour coding they have used in the ground labeling. I assumed pixels would be annotated 1 through 20 for each class but what I have got are 8 bit deep png images with pixel values (0-255).

For a certain pixel belonging to `aeroplane` class in `2007_000033.png`, I get the values: (128, 0, 0); while another pixel belonging to `train` class in `2007_000123.png`, gives the values : (128, 0, 192) and so on.

How do I differentiate them in different classes and do a one-hot encoding? Do I need to specify pixel values for each class (like searching pixels with (128, 0, 0) and encode them as 1 for class `aeroplane`)?

Sorry, I see a few similar questions on SO but nothing helped me. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably check the class of each pixel and map it to a certain colour. Check this out https://gist.github.com/wllhf/a4533e0adebe57e3ed06d4b50c8419ae.

Comment: Thanks @MattSt. This should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

I raised myself a similar question which confused me for quite sometime. And I think I found a possible explanation:

If you look at the  [file_download_and_convert_voc2012.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/download_and_convert_voc2012.sh), there are lines marked by "**# Remove the colormap in the ground truth annotations**". This part process the original SegmentationClass files and produce the raw segmented image files, which have each pixel value between 0 : 20. (If you may ask why, check this post: [Python: Use PIL to load png file gives strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676447/python-use-pil-to-load-png-file-gives-strange-results?noredirect=1#comment90316222_51676447))